# jenkins concurrent build with parameter

Tags: jenkins, concurrency, build

## What's I'm trying to solve

I've a job on Jenkins to trigger a shell script, which accepts parameter A and parameter B. These two parameters will have different value.
At the moment, user is able to select one of parameterA and parameterB, and it will trigger the job to run once.

What I am trying to do is allow user to select multiple parameterA and B. Essentially, it's a 2D parameter matrix. If user selects 1 in parameter A and 3 different value in parameter B, I want Jenkins to run 3 concurrent builds: A1B1, A1B2,A1B3.

## What's the problem

I took a look at the multiple configuration Jenkins project and it seems to allow using configuration matrix to have the 2D matrix. However, it's not a parameter selected by user and hence you can't control which one will be run.

I am wondering if there's any plugins that can help with this user case. I don't think this is a edge case since some projects should require generating builds for different platforms and variations.

Any idea or direction will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [Matrix Combinations Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Combinations+Plugin)

From the wiki page

> This plugin allows a user to choose which matrix combinations he wants
>   to run, as opposed to the default behaviour where jenkins runs all
>   combinations: Using:
>
> After clicking the build, the user gets a html table with a checkbox
>   for each matrix combination.
>
> After clicking the submit button, only checked combinations will run.

Comment: Thanks! That's the approach I took!